# Web Test Fails With SocketException

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, load-testing, web-testing

I have recorded a simple web test in VS 2013 Ultimate and im attempting to run it on a remote agent.

I get the following error:

```
Request failed: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:23109
```

[image]

If i change my run settings to only run the test locally it succeeds.

When i view the "Manage Test Controller" dialog the agents are registered and in the ready state.

I have checked the Controller and agent LAN settings and none of them is configured (or required) to use a proxy.

Does anyone have any idea whats going on?

Comment: Looks as if you are specifying "localhost" as the controller. What computer is specified in the "Controller" field of the "Roles" page of your *.testsettings" file? Als, is there a little yellow warning triangle, or any other symbol, to the right of the "Controller" field?

Comment: I am indeed specifying "localhost" as my controller. However there are no yellow warning triangles

Comment: "localhost" is not a remote computer. Have you installed the controller software on the computer you want to control the tests and have you configured the users and permissions as per the Microsoft documentation for the controller software? What about agent computers? Have you installed and configured the agent software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was the Internet Explorer security settings on the agents and also Internet explorer was configured to use a proxy on the agents.

I logged onto the server and checked this initially but as my own user account. I then checked by logging on as the user the agents run as and removed the configured proxy from IE, lowered the security settings and all was well.